# How can I wire up my new light? Old one was a fluorescent strip light

Tags: kitchens, ceiling, light

Also if I turn off electric at the mains so no electric in house at all am I quite safe and not likely to electrocute myself? 
[image][image][image]
Thanks

Comment: Whoever answers this, explain what that plastic connector is coming out of the ceiling.  And since the wires are now exposed, I certainly hope that you have the breaker or switch turned off.

Comment: Electrical wires are like guns.  They are loaded (live) until proven not to be.  The problem is, you never know what Some Genius did to your home before you got there.  That being said, Shutting off the mains SHOULD make it safe.  But do a quick check with a voltage tester to be sure.